# Is there a word for someone dodgy with tasks or chores?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Someone evasive when it comes to tasks. Someone not around when there are chores to do.

Answer (score 0):

This person is a **slacker** or a **shirker**.

[Slacker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slacker): a person who avoids work and responsibilities

[Shirk](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shirker): to evade the performance of an obligation; as noun: shirker